# Querying documents in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following sample document

```
[{
"Name" : "John doe",
"age"  : 22,
"email" : "john@doe.com"
},
{
"Name" : "William",
"age"  : 28,
"email" : "william@william.com"
},
{
"Name" : "jack",
"age"  : 22,
"email" : "jack@jack.com"
}]
```

I have an array of objects with me with the following structure
`[{'name':'jack','age':10},{'name':'john','age':20}]`
  How do I perform a query in the document in a way such that I can match the *name* field and *age* field of my array of objects of each element.
Basically, the *name* `jack` and the *age* `10` should query with the sample and after that the *name* `john` and the *age* `20` should perform the query.
I know that `$elemMatch` could have been used if it was the other way around where I had to query with single elements in an array. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean you have to query the database which matches the element objects?

Comment: @Tolsee Didn't quite get you.
I want to query the sample database which is the first snippet with each element of the second snippet which is a small array of objects having only the name and age field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not talking about searching the retrieved documents. You can search database like this:

```
    var searchArr = [{name:'jack',age:10},{name:'john', age:20}]

    searchArr.forEach(function(element){
        var query = Model.find(element)

        query.then(function(result){
            console.log(result)
        })
    })
```